# How to fix AngularJS directives (forms) breaking when using webcomponentjs bundle polyfill on edge/firefox/ie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am loading webcomponent.js bundle polyfill to be able to use shadow dom and custom elements. This bundle is loaded alongside angular, and now my angular directives such as form are not showing at all on firefox/edge/ie (chrome and safari are fine) and they are broken. Has anyone found a solution to this?.

I am using

```
import '../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite';
import '../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter';
```

When I use webcomponent-lite the form gets removed as below:
[image]

and when I remove it I get the form:
[image]
*This is an angular form

This is also posted on the webcomponentjs GitHub as [Issue #981](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/981) although I'm using AngularJS 1.x and they are talking about angular6.

Comment: what does "broken" mean? are you getting errors in the console?  can you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: Hi @Claies, so by broken, I mean the form component, for example, does not show at all, and there are no evident errors in the console or anything.
I'm not sure how to show you an example, as I'm basically just importing the webcomponents to the page and that's when angular form doesn't show. I have uploaded images to show. 
There is basically nor errors that are thrown!!

Comment: You really need to show some code.  It's not clear what you are talking about when you say "angular form", because that's not really a thing in Angular 1.x .  Are you meaning a directive that renders a form?